# Three.JS - Particles orbiting a point in random directions forming a sphere

Tags: three.js, particle-system

I have a particle system where all the particles are positioned at the same coordinates and one after another, in random directions, they (should) start orbiting the center of the scene forming a sphere.

What I managed to achieve until now is a group of Vector3 objects (the particles) that one after another start orbiting the center along the Z axis simply calculating their sine and cosine based on the current angle.

I'm not that good at math and I don't even know what to look for precisely.

Here's what I wrote:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

let container = document.getElementById('container'), 
    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(), 
    renderer, 
    camera, 
    maxParticles = 5000, 
    particlesDelay = 50, 
    radius = 50, 
    sphereGeometry, 
    sphere;

loader.crossOrigin = true;

function init() {

    let vw = window.innerWidth, 
        vh = window.innerHeight;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(vw, vh);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, vw / vh, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 200;
    camera.position.x = 30;
    camera.position.y = 30;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    scene.add(camera);

    let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    let axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper(50);
    scene.add(axisHelper);

    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);

}

function onResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);    

}

function draw() {

    sphereGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    sphereGeometry.dynamic = true;

    let particleTexture = loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/particle2.png'), 
        material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff, 
            size: 3, 
            transparent: true, 
            blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, 
            map: particleTexture, 
            depthWrite: false
        });

        for ( let i = 0; i < maxParticles; i++ ) {

            let vertex = new THREE.Vector3(radius, 0, 0);
            vertex.delay = Date.now() + (particlesDelay * i);
            vertex.angle = 0;
            sphereGeometry.vertices.push(vertex);

        }

        sphere = new THREE.Points(sphereGeometry, material);
        scene.add(sphere);

}

function update() {

    for ( let i = 0; i < maxParticles; i++ ) {

        let particle = sphereGeometry.vertices[i];

        if ( Date.now() > particle.delay ) {

            let angle = particle.angle += 0.01;

            particle.x = radius * Math.cos(angle);

            if ( i % 2 === 0 ) {
                particle.y = radius * Math.sin(angle);
            } else {
                particle.y = -radius * Math.sin(angle);
            }

        }


    }

    sphere.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

}

function render() {

    update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

}

init();
draw();
render();
```

And here's the JSFiddle if you want to see it live:
https://jsfiddle.net/kekkorider/qs6s0wv2/

**EDIT**: [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/kekkorider/qs6s0wv2/4/)

Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want each particle to rotate around a specific random axis. You can either let them follow a [parametric equation of a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73237/parametric-equation-of-a-circle-in-3d-space) in 3D space, or you can make use of THREE.js rotation matrices.

Right now all your particles are rotating round the vector (0, 0, 1). Since your particles start off on the x-axis, you want them all to rotate around a random vector in the y-z plane (0, y, z). This can be defined during the creation of the vertices:

```
vertex.rotationAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1);
vertex.rotationAxis.normalize();
```

now you can just call the `THREE.Vector3.applyAxisAngle(axis, angle)` method on each of your particles with the random rotation axis you created each update:

```
particle.applyAxisAngle(particle.rotationAxis, 0.01);
```

To sum up, this is how it should look like:

**draw()**:

```
...
for ( let i = 0; i < maxParticles; i++ ) {

    let vertex = new THREE.Vector3(radius, 0, 0);
    vertex.delay = Date.now() + (particlesDelay * i);
    vertex.rotationAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1);
    vertex.rotationAxis.normalize();
    sphereGeometry.vertices.push(vertex);
}
...
```

**update()**:

```
...
for ( let i = 0; i < maxParticles; i++ ) {

    let particle = sphereGeometry.vertices[i];

    if ( Date.now() > particle.delay ) {
        particle.applyAxisAngle(particle.rotationAxis, 0.01); 
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Hi @micnil, your solution worked as a charm, thanks a lot for your help :)
I added a link to a working example in case someone else needs it.

Comment: @micnil Could you clarify something for me? I've been studying this example because it produces a really cool effect, and I plan on building a "black hole" scene. 

How does a `vertex.rotationAxis`, which is a Vector3 with a random y and z value, cause the particles to rotate in random directions? I've been poking at jsfiddle for a couple of days now and I still cannot understand what is creating this effect of particles forming a sphere. I see that `applyAxisAngle` is the magic that creates this, however, I don't understand why adjusting y and z for each particle's `rotationAxis` does this.

Comment: @AlexFallenstedt Basically I created a vector that the particles can rotate around. Its a bit hard to explain in text in a comment without images and figures. But consider this version of your fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/qs6s0wv2/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/qs6s0wv2/5/). Try pressing "run" a coupl of times and you'll see how the particle behaves when its rotation axis changes.

Comment: @AlexFallenstedt Maybe even clearer: [https://jsfiddle.net/qs6s0wv2/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/qs6s0wv2/7/), see how the particle is always at right angle to the rotation axis.

Comment: This is clearing up a lot of confusion. thank you @micnil. :)